# Storing images in storage folder of laravel, and fetching it by a http request is not working

Tags: image, laravel, heroku, filesystems

I have deployed laravel application in heroku. I am storing images in storage folder of laravel and trying to fetch it by defining a route. It was working well on local, but when i trying to do the same on server, then its not showing the images. I thought that storage folder is inside the laravel, so it should work fine, but its not working.

Can i store images in public folder by creating a named folder "gallery" inside that and put that gallery folder in gitignore. so will the gitignore folder be vanished when i will push the laravel project again?

Other options are using another file system. Most of them are paid, so i was thinking to save the images in database, is that the good idea or i should move to files only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `storage` directory should have right permission.
You should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.
Create the symbolic link:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot save images in database, only their names or links etc. I implemented the same thing you did by naming the files to their path and storing that to the database and then using it to fetch the data from folder on sever

Comment: Ya. that i am doing also, but not able to fetch the file, because some problem happening on heroku